# Regex to match string that contains 3 strings separated by vertical bar `|`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to match a string pattern which has first 4 characters, then the "|" symbol, then 4 characters, then the "|" symbol again and then a minimum of 7 characters.

For example, `"test|test|test123"` should be matched.

I tried `RegExp("^([a-za-z0-9-|](4)[a-za-z0-9-|](5)[a-za-z0-9-|](3)+)$")` for this, but it didn't match my test case.

**test|test|test1234**

Comment: but your pattern should satisfy what type of string?

Comment: What's the question? Can you give more examples of true and false matches?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: what kind of string should pass the test, what strings shouldn't. Please elaborate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want first 4 character and then "|' symbol and 4 character and then "|' symbol and minimum 7 corrector. ex : test|test|test123 this string should give true else return false.

Comment: @rameshshan please update the question. No one is going to see the comment.

Comment: I want first 4 character and then "|' symbol and 4 character and then "|' symbol and minimum 7 corrector. ex : test|test|test123 this string should give true else return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ramesh, does this do what you want?

`^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{4}\|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{4}\|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{7,}$`

You can try it at https://regex101.com/r/jilO6O/1

For example, the following will be matched:

- test|test|test123
- a1-0|b100|c10-200
- a100|b100|c100200

But the following will not:

- a10|b100|c100200
- a100|b1002|c100200
- a100|b100|c10020

#### Tips on modifying your original code.

You have "a-za-z" where you probably intended "a-zA-Z", to allow either upper or lower case.

To specify the number of characters to be exactly 4, use "{4}". You were nearly there with your round brackets, but they need to be curly, to specify a count.

To specify a range of number of characters, use "{lowerLimit,upperLimit}". Leaving the upper limit blank allows unlimited repeats.

We need to escape the "|" character because it has the special meaning of "alternate", in regular expressions, i.e. "a|b" matches either "a" or "b". By writing it as "\|" the regex interpreter knows we want to match the "|" character itself.